# What is the difference between $name and $$name?

Tags: php, forms, email, variables

I have been working on an email form and came across a problem.

```
<?php 
 $to = $_REQUEST['sendto'] ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name"; 
 $fields{"Company"} = "Company"; 
 $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 
 $fields{"list"} = "Mailing List"; 
 $fields{"Message"} = "Message"; 

 $body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 $headers2 = "From: noreply@YourCompany.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.oursite.com";

 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: http://www.YourDomain.com/thankyou.html" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify webmaster@YourCompany.com"; } 
 }
}
 ?>
```

I have tried to run it but keep having errors with the `$name` variable. I did some research and found out that I could use `$$name` also. I ran through it and that didn't work, so I decided I should change other parts of the script. I need to know whether `$name` or `$$name`. I did some research and found out that `$$name` is a reference variable, and `$name`is just a variable. I need to know what the outcome  would be for each one, and which one I should use.

Comment: What are the errors you keep having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$name is probably not what you are looking for

```
$abc = 'def';
$name = 'abc';

echo $name;  // this will output abc
echo $$name; // this will output def
```

You can read about php variables from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable variable:

```
$x = 'foo';
$foo = 'bar';
$$x = 'baz';
echo "$x $foo"; // outputs 'foo baz', not 'foo bar';
```

`$$var` is basically saying "take the contents of $var, and use that contents as the name of a variable, and assign to that variable".

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use an array

```
$fields = array(); 
$fields["Name"] = $_REQUEST['Name']; 
$fields["Company"] = $_REQUEST['Company']; 
$fields["Email"] = $_REQUEST['Email']; 
$fields["Phone"] = $_REQUEST['Phone']; 
$fields["Mailing list"] = $_REQUEST['List']; 
$fields["Message"] = $_REQUEST["Message"];
```

Your script will work fine now.

If you want to include the data from $_REQUEST, try this way.

You can paste the php form too, and we can come up with a more optimized solution

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I wanted. I wanted to  know which one I should use in my script

Answer (score 0):

When you add a $ in front of the variable you are making it a dynamic variable. This is handy if you want to be able to switch between variables.